# Switch tables based on parameters selected in CR 2008

Tags: database, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal reports 2008 and my requirement is:

- if I select a parameters (like it be %) then it should use a different view
- if it is not, then it should use the same view
  Can I do that using a query in Crystal reports?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way to do this in Crystal.  Perhaps in .net.  If you use an application like Millet Software's Visual Cut to schedule, run and distribute your reports you can set it up in such a way that the method call that triggers the report job has the ability to override the default connection parameters.  That itself can be a variable too - override or not based on certain criteria.

I've deployed it in a way that uses 1 report to recursively connect to a list of different (but same schema) databases to run versions of the report, one after the other.

FULL DISCLOSURE

I do not work for Millet Software, I do not receive referral bonuses and I do not receive a reseller bonus. I simply have had great experience with them and wanted you to be aware of the possibility, not solicit your business.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using database, which supports scripts or stored procedures you can do this using a command or a stored procedure. Inside the script check the value of the parameter and call one or another query.

Sample code for SQL server will look like this:

if CHARINDEX(@Parameter,'%')>0
  SELECT * FROM View1
ELSE
  SELECT * FROM View2